# How to use picker as Int in qr code generator with swiftui

Tags: swiftui, integer, qr-code

I am new to swift and i am using swiftui to create a qr code generator. I want to use a picker to select number and it shows in the qr code, when i finished the picker and i was trying to add function as qr code generator and the integer needs to be convert to string, so it can be used in the function. How can i make the function work with Integer?

Here is my code which i tried:

I used age as Integer with picker

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct QRCode: View {
    @State private var selectedAge = 1
    let age = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
    @State var navigated = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Picker(“Select Age”, selection: $selectedAge) {
                    ForEach(age,id:\.self) {
                        ages in Text(“\(ages)”)                 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//Below is the other view with the function

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct Generate: View {
    @Binding var Ages: Int

    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Image(uiImage: GenerateQRCode(old: old))
                .interpolation(.none)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }
    }

    func GenerateQRCode(old: Int)-> UIImage {
        let com = Ages
        let con = com.data(using: .uft8)

        filter.setValue(con, forKey: “inputMessage”)
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: “xmark”) ?? UIImage()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple approach to "...make the function work with Integer".
Note the name change `ages/age` for clarity.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        QRCode()
    }
}

struct QRCode: View {
    @State private var selectedAge = 1
    let ages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]  // <-- ages
    @State var navigated = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Picker("Select Age", selection: $selectedAge) {
                    ForEach(ages, id: \.self) { age in
                        Text("\(age)")
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(.wheel) // <-- for testing
                Generate(age: $selectedAge)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Generate: View {
    @Binding var age: Int
    
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: GenerateQRCode(old: age))
            .interpolation(.none)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
    }
    
    func GenerateQRCode(old: Int)-> UIImage {
        let data = String(old).data(using: .utf8)    // <-- here
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage") // <-- here
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It works in my code, i was thinking convert int to string outside the function, after your answer, it should be wrote inside the function, thank you